# INNER JOIN com OR clause

Tags: sqlite

Eu tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT linha._id, 
       linha.numero_onibus, 
       linha.nome, 
       percurso.nome 
FROM linha
INNER JOIN percurso ON linha._id = percurso.id_linha
AND (linha.numero_onibus LIKE ? OR linha.nome LIKE ?) COLLATE NOCASE
```

Quando a condição `linha.numero_onibus LIKE ?` é falsa, a consulta não retorna resultados. O que e tenho que fazer para que, mesmo se a condição `linha.numero_onibus LIKE ?` for falsa, ele proceder com a consulta e me retornar os resultados de `linha.nome LIKE ?` ?

Comment: A sua query parece OK, exceto pela segunda parte do ON, que deveria estar no WHERE. Mas isso não faz diferença no resultado em alguns SGBDs (não sei ao certo como é no sqlite, então vale a pena testar.

Comment: Acredito que o problema ocorreu pela lógica da query. A condição `linha.numero_onibus LIKE ? OR linha.nome LIKE ?` sempre trará resultados de `linha.numero_onibus LIKE ?` pois essa condição sempre será verdadeira. Como também estava com problemas de performance, acabei criando uma tabela [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1) para resolver o problema da query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta rápida (vai precisar testar):

```
 SELECT
 linha._id, 
 linha.numero_onibus, 
 linha.nome, 
 percurso1.nome as the_nome_caso_1,
 percurso2.nome as the_nome_caso_2

 FROM linha

 LEFT OUTER JOIN percurso as percurso1 ON linha._id = percurso1.id_linha
 AND linha.nome LIKE ?

 LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN percurso as percurso2 ON linha._id = percurso2.id_linha
 AND linha.numero_onibus LIKE ?
```

Então você vai usar duas vezes a tabela percurso, mas com "alias".

Se você usar INNER JOIN e a query der um resultado falso, não vai ter resultado algum.

Comment: eu já tentei com o LEFT OUTER JOIN e mesmo assim não trouxe resultado. A consulta só funciona quando executo no sqlite, quando implemento no android ele não me retorna valores.

Testei dessa forma

´SELECT  linha._id, 
 linha.numero_onibus, 
 linha.nome, 
CASE WHEN p1.nome IS NOT NULL THEN 
 p1.nome ELSE p2.nome END
AS percurso
FROM  linha
LEFT OUTER JOIN percurso  AS p1 ON linha._id = p1.id_linha
AND linha.numero_onibus LIKE '%10%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN percurso AS p2 ON linha._id = p2.id_linha
AND linha.nome LIKE '%10%'
WHERE p1.nome IS NOT NULL or p2.nome IS NOT NULL´

Comment: Ah, então se você tem resultado no sqlite "fora" de Android, mas não tem resulado "em" Android, o problema não e o query. Precisa verificar se a conexão e coreta e tambem se você tem valor na base de dados. Para isso, e melhor baixar os dados do sqlite no seu computador para verificar.
Para isso, se você usa Android Studio, precisa dar uma olhada no baxio da janela, no Android DDMS. Tem posibilidade de ver os dados da tablets. Os dados de sqlLite são em:

Comment: Os dados de sqlIte são em:
data/data/com.xxxxxxx.module/databases/com.xxxxxx.module.database

Comment: Parece meio bobo dizer isso, mas verifique a versão do SQLite..

Comment: Eu notei depois de muito tempo, que em muitos casos estamos buscando reposta bem longe de nos, quando a resposta certa esta bem perto. Então a resposta de Daniel e um paso interesante!